# Reporting Services How to get the Count() value from IIF

Tags: reporting-services

I have this table with a column named Open_Time which contain a datetime value. I would like to have another column named Total Ticket In June with the total count of ticket in June, so I've inserted the expression like below:

=Count((IIF(DatePart("m",Fields!Open_Time.Value,0,0) = "6",1,0)))

but there seems to be an error. To make myself clear, the table should look like this:

```
Assigned Name    Ticket ID    Open_Time    Total Ticket in June

Ivan             001          3/28/2014            2
                 002          6/24/2014
                 003          6/11/2014
```

I would like to get value "2", which is the total number of ticket in June. Any idea? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to a `Sum` aggregate instead of `Count` (based on your `IIF`, `Count` will count every row instead of giving you a total number of occurences):

```
=Sum(IIF(DatePart("m",Fields!Open_Time.Value,0,0) = 6, 1, 0))
```

From your table it's hard to tell your row groupings, but keep in mind that you'll only get the sum you expect if that expression is on a totals row (i.e. if you use that expression on the detail row it will simply list 1 or 0 for each date).

Comment: Thanks man! it worked! Done the grouping and it shows exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
=Count((IIF(DatePart(dateinterval.Month,Fields!Open_Time.Value,0,0) = 6,1,0)))